# how to open activities from a main menu screen

Tags: android, eclipse

This is the code i used but when i click on any of the buttons **except** ProfileHandler & calculateHandler arent working the only thing that changes is the name of the activity but it stays at the MainActivity screen

```
    public void ProfileHandler(View view){

    Intent Intent=new Intent (MainActivity.this, ProfileMainActivity.class);
    startActivity(Intent);
}

    public void new_profile_handler(View view){
    Intent Intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewProfileMainActivity.class);
    startActivity(Intent);
}
     public void add_activity_handler(View view){
        Intent Intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, InputUserActivity.class);
    startActivity(Intent);
}

    public void View_Activities_Handler(View view){

 Intent Intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewAllActsActivity.class);
    startActivity(Intent);
}



public void calculateHandler(View view){
    Intent Intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalculateMainActivity.class);
    startActivity(Intent);
}

public void Goal_Handler(View view){
    Intent Intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, GoalMainActivity.class);
    startActivity(Intent);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure these methods get called when you press the buttons? And please rename your class members to be compliant with standard naming convention, it's hard for most people to read your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use camelCasedNamingConvention instead of a random mix of camelCase and underscored_naming

Why are you passing the view to these methods as you are not using it in within them?

Are you sure in those activities you have specified a valid and well defined content layout?

setConentView(R.layout.some_activity) - this should be pointing to a different xml file that you have specified in your layout folder.

I dont know how you call these methods, but you can use a SWITCH statement or if you have problems with switch statement, you could try multiple if/else statements like this:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private Button buttonOne;
private Button buttonTwo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
        buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTwo);
        buttonOne.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.buttonOne) {
            Intent startActivityOne = new Intent (MyClass.this, ActivityOne.class);
                        startActivity(startActivityOne);
        } else if (id == R.id.buttonTwo) {
            Intent startActivityTwo = new Intent (MyClass.this, ActivityTwo.class);
                        startActivity(startActivityTwo);            
        }
}
```

and in class ActivityOne you should:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);
```

in class ActivityTwo you should:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
```

which are different xml files you have defined in your layout folder.

Note: in Java its preferred to use camelCase, but with the xml files in Android you should use underscored_names and avoid putting digits there.